# FaceDetector.Builder().build(getApplicationContext()) gives me errors

Tags: android, face-detection, google-vision

I'm trying to make an Android app that takes one picture when it detects a face. I was trying to follow [Google's Mobile Vision FaceDetector Pipeline](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/face-tracker-tutorial) but I can't get past

```
FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder().build(getApplicationContext());
```

`Builder` is bright red and says cannot resolve symbol `Builder`.

I've checked my Gradle files and my Android Manifest, and they're the same as [Google's](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker).

I can't figure out what to do next.

Also, if someone could point me to a good tutorial on FaceDetection that uses the Camera2 API, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that there is an old legacy FaceDetector class in Android:

```
android.media.FaceDetector
```

This is NOT what you want to use.  The class for the newer mobile vision API is here:

```
com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector
```

Comment: Wow! Great. This is what I exactly want. thanks buddy. u just saved my time.